# Check String is in a range of numbers Java

Tags: java, string, int

Trying to design a simple lottery program. Everything works except checking if the numbers entered are between 1 to 59.

Exercise says the numbers must be stored in a `String` variable.

so

```
if(num<0 || num>59) //wont work for me
```

Tried making another variable

```
int numConverted = Integer.parseInt(num)
```

We haven't covered converting `String` to `int` in class though so I don't think this is what expected. Got confused trying that way anyway so probably this is wrong.

Here is the code I have currently.

```
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String num=""; //num variable is empty untill user inputs numbers

    for(int i =0; i<6; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your number between 1-59");
        num = num +" "+ scan.nextLine(); 
    }

    System.out.println("Ticket printed £2. Your numbers are " + num);
}
```

Comment: a String is not a numerical value, nor can it be used as one.

Comment: Why not use the `nextInt()` method of Scanner to fill a primitive array (`int[] numbers = new int[5]`) instead?

Comment: You need to convert it to a number in order to perform numerical comparisons. Give your approach with the ``int`` variable a chance!

Comment: ... actually you will need `nextInt()` followed by `nextLine` to consume `EOL` (end-of-line) character(s).

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` is just right for this context, frankly.

Comment: ***Exercise says the numbers must be stored in a string variable.***

Comment: @LouisWasserman I agree completely.  `Integer.parseInt` is a very good way of doing this.  I do however find it completely bizarre that OP specifically said they didn't want to do it with `parseInt`, and then accepted an answer that uses `parseInt`, and basically repeats what they've already said they know how to do.

Comment: Nitpick: `Integer.parseInt(num)` will fail (throw an `IllegalArgumentException`) if the entered value exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. `long converted = Long.parseLong(num)` would be better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oh I see what you are trying to do

This is what you want

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


String allNums = "";


for(int i =0; i<6; i++) 
{
    System.out.println("Enter your number between 1-59");
    int num = scan.nextInt();//Take the number in as an int 

    if(num >0 && num < 59)//Check if it is in range
    {
        allNums += num + " ";//if it is add it to a string
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Number not in range");
        i--;//go back one iteration if its not in range
    }


}

System.out.println("Ticket printed £2. Your numbers are " + allNums);
```

Comment: but it says  the numbers must be stored in a string

Comment: Michael: he also says he wants to compare numerical values in Strings. No, he doesn't want Strings, because if he does, he won't be able to decently compare them the way he needs to, he 's just confused about the datatypes and their abbilities

Answer (score 1):

In your posted code it's obvious that you want the User to supply 6 specific numerical values. These values are appended to the String variable named **num** (space delimited). You need to obviously do a few things here:

1) Make sure the value supplied by the user is indeed a numerical value;

2) Make sure the numerical values supplied fall within the minimum and maximum scope of the lottery itself (which you have stated is: 1 to 59);

3) Make sure the number entered by the User hasn't been supplied already.

You've been tasked to store the entered values into a String data type variable and that is all fine but at some point you want to carry out value comparisons to make sure that all the entered values actually play within the limits of the lottery.

When the User completes his/her entries, you end up with a space delimited string held in the **num** string variable. You now need to make sure that these values entered are indeed....numbers from 1 to 59 and none contain alpha characters.

In my opinion (and this is only because you need to store entered values into a String variable), it's best to use your String variable to gather User input, then test the input to make sure it is indeed a string representation of an actual integer number. Once this is established then we test to make sure if falls within the value min/max limits (1-59). Now we need to test to make sure the number entered hasn't already been entered before for this ticket.

Of course with each test described above, if one fails then the User should be prompted to re-enter a proper value. You can do this by utilizing a **while** loop. Plenty examples of this in StackOverflow but here's a quick example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String ticketNumbers = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Boolean isOK = false;
    while (!isOK) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter your desired 6 ticket numbers:\n"
                + "(from 1 to 59 only)");
        String num = scan.nextLine(); 
        //Is the string entered an actual integer number?
        //We use the String.matches() method for this with
        //a regular expression.
        if(!num.matches("\\d+")) {
            System.out.println("You must supply a numerical value! "
                    + "Try Again...");
            continue;
        }
        if (ticketNumbers.contains(num + " ")) {
            System.out.println("The number you supplied has already been chosen!"
                    + " Try Again...");
            continue;
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(num) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(num) <= 59) {
            ticketNumbers+= num + " ";
            isOK = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The number you supply must be from "
                    + "1 to 59! Try Again...");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Ticket printed £2. Your numbers are " + ticketNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about -

```
if(Integer.parseInt(num) < 0 || Integer.parseInt(num) > 59)
```

This should work, place it after the input.

If it works, please mark this as correct, I need the rep!!!

Comment: OP says in the question they don't want to use `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: Hmm, he said he made another variable...  I've done it without that, but you may be right.

Comment: This seemed like exactly what i needed but when ever this code is executed it throws an exception

Comment: @ChrisLynch So you're actually checking a whole series of numbers, not just one?  That wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Im checking every number the user inputs,  if that is 1 number or 6 numbers it doesn't make a difference does it?

Comment: Well, yeah, "is my string a series of numbers" is a completely different question from "is my string a single number".  Never mind - my answer lets you deal with both cases.  But you really should have asked your question more clearly.  @ChrisLynch

Comment: Check each scan, before adding is all.  Scan into a temporary string,  If it passes, add it.  If it doesn't, ask again.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be add available numbers (suppose it wont grow more than 60. You can use a loop to add to this as well)

```
String numbers[] = {"1","2","3", "..."};
```

Then inside the loop

```
 Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(num);
```

You can remove prefixing zero in order avoid conflicts with values like `'02'`

Here everything is `String` related.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to explicitly convert to `int`, you could use a regular expression.

```
if (num.matches("[1-5]?[0-9]")) {
    ...
```

This checks whether the String consists of (1) **maybe** a digit from 1 to 5, followed by (2) **definitely** a digit from 0 to 9.  That'll match any number in the range 0-59.

If you've got a whole series of numbers separated by spaces, you could expand this to cover a whole series like this.

```
if (num.matches("([1-5]?[0-9]\\s+)*[1-5]?[0-9]")) {
```

This matches any number of repetitions (including zero) of "a number followed by spaces", followed by a single repetition without a space.  The `"\\s"` means "any whitespace character", the `"+"` after it means "one or more of what precedes", and the `"*"` means "zero more of what precedes" - which in this case is the term in parentheses.